# If acceleration is zero, does it mean that I haven't applied any force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, friction, inertial-frames

Suppose I *push* a **heavy object** with a **huge force** and it doesn't accelerate. Does it happen just because of *friction*?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Jun Seo-He's answer:

> Does it happen just because of friction?

Not just because of friction. Think what will happen if another person pushes that object to the opposite direction that you are trying to push. That force also contributes to cancel out your force and any other force to the opposite direction. So you should consider all forces acting on that object, not only friction, those making the net force zero.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the net force exerted on the object is 0.You must take into account the static friction as well.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the net force acting on the body is Zero.
Using:
(Force Vector)= (Mass)(Acceleration Vector).
This may be due to multiple reasons:

1. One obvious reason is friction because if the object is heavy the large normal force will help even static friction to hold back the large applied force.
2. If the object carries an electrostatic charge, additionally applied electric fields may help in cancelling out the large applied force, thereby the required static friction may even get down to zero.
   And depending upon the magnitude of the electrostatic field applied the force of friction may even act in direction of the large external force.
3. The same may be done using high-speed wind in specially designed wind-tunnels used by Wind Energy Engineers, used to study impacts of wind of skyscrapers, and also by Aeronautical Engineers to simulate flights in tunnels.